# Does lapply apply the function orderly?

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of functions

```
functions <- list(f1, f2, f3, ...)
```

And I need to pass an object `x` through all the functions. I could do it by:

```
for (fun in functions){
  fun(x)
}
```

The functions do not return anything, but their order is important, i.e. `f1(x)` must be applied before `f2(x)`.

Thus, I'm thinking on using `lapply`:

```
lapply(functions, function(fun) fun(x))
```

But I don't know if `lapply` applies first the first function of the list `functions` or if it follows another order. With the loop I assure the ordering but it may go slower.

Any idea?

Comment: Note: You'd likely run into scoping problems.

Comment: `lapply()` will go in order of the list. But it is more likely that the loop will go faster actually. `lapply()` will attempt to store output and allocate space for it. If your functions do not return anything and you are calling only for side effects, that will just be extra overhead.

Comment: Okay! Then I'll keep the loop, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording of the question "pass x through ..." suggests that you think this will accomplish a "composition", i.e. a serial application of functions to results from prior applications. Neither of your proposed solutions will do that although you could rework your `for` loop to do so. Take a look at the `?funprog` help page which I am shamelessly quoting in part:

```
## Iterative function application:
Funcall <- function(f, ...) f(...)
## Compute log(exp(acos(cos(0))
Reduce(Funcall, list(log, exp, acos, cos), 0, right = TRUE)
```

Compare the results of a `for` loop version with the `Reduce` version:

```
> flist <- list(log, exp, acos, cos)
> arg <- 0; for (f in flist) {arg <- f(arg)}
> arg
[1] 6.123234e-17
> Funcall <- function(f, ...) f(...)
> ## Compute log(exp(acos(cos(0))
> Reduce(Funcall, list(log, exp, acos, cos), 0, right = TRUE)
[1] 0
```

This shows that `<something>` is actually happening:

```
arg <- 0; for (f in flist) {arg <- f(arg);cat(arg,"\n")}
-Inf 
0 
1.570796 
6.123234e-17
```

But they are not the same since the `right=TRUE` actually reverses the order of application and explains the trivial difference in the final result. Compare:

```
arg <- 0; for (f in rev(flist)) {arg <- f(arg);cat(arg,"\n")}
```

Comment: I was not looking for a composition, just needed to apply several functions in a determined order (they make side effects, but do not return anything). But thanks for the answer! If nobody else responds within a day I'll accept it!

Comment: Then you can just change that Funcall to have `f()` instead of `f(...)` and return anything.